# How to perform post-hoc with logistic regression in SPSS? (Two dichotomous IVs)

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, spss, post-hoc

I performed a logistic regression in SPSS using two IVs (both dichotomous) and found a significant interaction effect. Now I want to understand where the differences come from.

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ V1_a⠀⠀⠀⠀V1_b

V2_a⠀⠀group A⠀⠀group B

V2_b⠀⠀group C⠀⠀group D

In this case, how can I compare group A with group B?
Is there any Syntax code?

Answer (score 2):

The LOGISTIC REGRESSION procedure (Binary Logistic Regression in the menus) doesn't offer an easy way to do this without doing something like creating a single four-level grouping variable with a distinct value for the cells of the 2x2 classification and then contrasting the appropriate cells when using that new variable in the analysis. The overall model results would be the same, and the three degrees of freedom for that new variable would represent the two main effects and the interaction, though not in an easily discernible way.

In the NOMREG procedure (Multinomial Logistic Regression), you can use a TEST subcommand to compare cells directly, but if you're not familiar with estimable functions and overparameterized models, getting the coefficients right to get the test can be tricky.

A way to do this using dialog boxes is to use the GENLIN (Generalized Linear Models) procedure to fit the model and to use the EMMEANS options to specify the interaction term and pairwise comparisons among the cells of that term, which would include the one you want.

The GENLINMIXED (Generalized Linear Mixed Models) procedure can also be used to fit the model (skip repeated and random effects, just use fixed effects) and with EMMEANS there you can specify the interacation and contrasts among levels of one of the factors, or simple main effects comparisons, which is what you want.